# MacBook Pro does not detect the third screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi, displayport

I am trying to connect two Dell screens to my Macbook Pro 13" via a Dell dock. One screen is using HDMI cable and the other one a DisplayPort cable to connect to the dock and I am connecting the MacBook using a type-c cable. My mac is running the latest version of Catalina.

However, the third screen is not detected by my MacBook Pro. It just recognises the screen that is connected by HDMI. The third screen is just mirroring the second one.

How can I configure it to detect the third screen and stop mirroring?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *Which* MacBook Pro do you have?

Comment: Hi @Allan my PC is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports).

Comment: When you say "One screen is using HDMI cable" is it directly connected to the dock or to the MacBook?